# Filter grade on the basis of obtained point in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to mySQL and I have below db table in mysql:

```
table : Grades

---------------------------
| sr   | grade   | point  |
---------------------------  
| 1    | E       | 0      |
| 2    | D       | 21     |
| 3    | C       | 41     |
| 4    | B       | 61     |
| 5    | A       | 81     |
---------------------------
```

There may be n numbers of grades and points in table.
Suppose a student gets 35 points (between 21 and 41) then he will score grade D.
A student gets 56 points (between 41 and 61) then he will score grade C.

Need to create query to filter grade on the basis of obtained point.

Please help.

Comment: Please try to mention what you have tried and also update the question with desired output

Comment: Surely 21-41 is D. Otherwise what does 82 points equal?

Comment: Strawberry, yes are right. for 82 grade should be D.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS 
( SELECT s.name, 
         g.grade,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.name ORDER BY g.grade DESC) rn
  FROM students s
  JOIN grades g ON s.point >= g.point
)
SELECT name, grade
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: @dan1st ??? what may be unclear in this simple code? Study "WITH clause" and "ROW_NUMBER() function" in User manual. Maybe execute the subquery from `cte` and investigate its output for to see how this works in practice.

Comment: It is just because code-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: @dan1st I will not copy rows from User Manual only, because I have no anything to add to them. It is easier to delete the answer - for me personally. Create your answer - with the same code and explanations, and I'll do it easily. I'm not interested in reputation points.

Comment: I (by myself) am not really really interested in this particular answer. Your answer just got flagged as `Very low Quality` and the way to go with that is (often) to just write a comment telling the author that an explaination would improve the answer and do not delete it. I could also have commented something like `While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.`.

Comment: @dan1st Imagine that I'll add explanations like "`FROM students s JOIN grades g ON s.point >= g.point` code part selects only rows where `point` from `students` table is not less than `point` in `grades` table". Idiotism, is it?